# generating count data using group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data like

```
column
1
1
57
57
57
1
1
57
57
```

I need to generate count data like

```
count
2
3
2
2
```

using mysql query. I have tried `group by` but it groups all the values also i couldn't group by any other fields. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

find the screenshot in this link
[image]

**Update:**
My end goal is to get the time spend by the user on each course . like the user who has ID 1 have spend time from `1177924991` to `1177925038` ( here `1177925038` is one second minus the next course visit time) on course id 1

Comment: count on the field with group by should work... What is the structure of the table and what is the query that you have tried?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that `SELECT *,count(*)
FROM  mdl_log ml
where ml.userid = 1
AND TIME >1177891200
AND TIME <1177977600
group by course` i am trying to extract data from mdl_log (moodle logs table)

Comment: How do you distinguish between the first group of three 57 and the second group of two 57. There must be another identifier which needs to be used in the group by

Comment: post your table structure also... and data that you had with above rows

Comment: Can you define what are you trying to achieve? Get the count of what? Why does the order of the rows matter why can't you group them all together?

Comment: It seems like i need at least 10 reputation points to add images so i have mentioned a link to the image. @Odinn i think the screenshot will answer your question.

Comment: you need to have a separate column that defines why info - 57 with ids 412340, 412342, 412373 differs from info - 57 with ids 412444 and 412478

Comment: @SKV since this is a table inside moodle, i donot have any meta data like the one which u asked for.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
SELECT COUNT(columnname) 
FROM  `tablename` 
GROUP BY columnname
```

This will do the needful.

UPDATE

I am getting following result set on running this query :
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it will not serve the purpose. OP has mentioned the expected result.

Comment: No this query is returning like `column 4 5`. As Aziz said that's not what i wanted.

Comment: you mean you also need to have some more columns so that you can know what count is for which value ? please provide your table structure for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM  `tablename` 
GROUP BY `info`
```

Comment: this query also doesn't serve my purpose. I have made an update to the question, check that for better understanding.

Comment: I am getting 6,18,19,1,21,1,1 but the data i wanted is 2,3,2,2,2,8

Comment: @code4cerlin I think you need to get the info colomn value also so that you can count the value of this one from the tables also. do that.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Query:

```
Select `course`, count(*) from `tablename`
group by `course`
```